# passing an array to a .php file using post in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, .post

I am trying to post an existing array in jquery using `$.post` to a **evaluate.php** page. I tried to serialize it and send it. But its not working. I get a internal server error. Can somebody suggest a method for me to post my array? Very much in need of help.

```
 <?php  
             function radioevaluation($qnum) {

              echo "<script> $(document).ready(function(){
                            var x= ".$qnum.";   
                        $('#q'+x+'verify').click(function(){

                                var answerarray = [];                           
                    answerarray['answer'] =$('input[name=q'+x+']:checked').val();

                            answerarray['qnum']= x;
                            var answer =jQuery.param(answerarray);

                            $.post('evaluate.php',answer,function(data){                        
                                var a= data;        
                                alert(a.result);    

                            }, 'json');

                        });
                    });</script>";
                }
?>
```

Comment: The error means there is something wrong in your php script. You can see the error in the error log.

Comment: I am getting no error if im passing my data like ` $.post('evaluate.php',{answer:xxxxx,qnum:x},function(data){                        
                                var a= data;        
                                alert(a.result);    

                            }, 'json'); `

So I think my php script is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Sorry I missed your second comment.

I think you want to define `answerarray` not as an array but like so:

```
var answerarray = {};
```

Comment: I have checked it already. As i have mentioned above, I dont get an error if I  pass it like `$.post('evaluate.php',{answer:XXXXX,qnum:XXXX} `.

Comment: @HemanthAnnavarapu - edited my answered based on your comment

Comment: It's working!! Thank you so much,sir!
sorry, I could'nt vote up, Don't have enough rep!